# Maven tomcat Dependencies not downloading in eclipse; RSA premaster secret error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am trying to run tomcat through maven using : **mvn tomcat7:run**
It is trying to download dependencies, but getting error in many of the POMs

```
#NOTE: This is a Maven Resolver internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Thu Apr 16 02:07:47 IST 2020
@default-central-https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1586983067650
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.apache.tomcat\:tomcat-coyote\:pom\:7.0.47 from/to central (https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: RSA premaster secret error
```

also, below error is showing in console :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) on project in28Minutes-springmvc: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run failed: Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar:2.2 -> org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-coyote:jar:7.0.47: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-coyote:jar:7.0.47: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-coyote:pom:7.0.47 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): RSA premaster secret error: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Did you get the full stack and/or debug log as recommended?

Comment: Yes, i did. In debug logs, it is showing that "[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.tomcat.maven/maven-metadata.xml in local < mavenrepository> ". and also for some other meta data files. As i checked, the files are present and it is again trying to download the files from cloud repo but error is coming like "[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.tomcat.maven/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): RSA premaster secret error" Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error;